# using lightbox on webpage with the same js code multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a really great lightbox script from [osvaldas.info](http://osvaldas.info/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly). With this script the following html code is needed:

```
<a href="/img/gallery-1.jpg" data-imagelightbox="a"><img src="/img/thumb_1.jpg"></a>
<a href="/img/gallery-2.jpg" data-imagelightbox="a"><img src="/img/thumb_1.jpg"></a>
<a href="/img/gallery-3.jpg" data-imagelightbox="a"><img src="/img/thumb_1.jpg"></a>
<a href="/img/gallery-4.jpg" data-imagelightbox="a"><img src="/img/thumb_1.jpg"></a>
<a href="/img/gallery-5.jpg" data-imagelightbox="a"><img src="/img/thumb_1.jpg"></a>
<a href="/img/gallery-6.jpg" data-imagelightbox="a"><img src="/img/thumb_1.jpg"></a>
```

The next gallery on the page would be used with `data-imagelightbox="b"` or something like that.

At the end of my HTML File I have to define this gallery like the following:

```
var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox="a"]';
var lightbox = $( selector ).imageLightbox(
{
  quitOnDocClick: false,
  onStart: function() { overlayOn(); closeButtonOn( lightbox ); arrowsOn( lightbox, selector ); },
  onEnd: function() { overlayOff(); closeButtonOff(); arrowsOff(); },
  onLoadStart: function() { },
  onLoadEnd: function() { $( '.imagelightbox-arrow' ).css( 'display', 'block' ); }
});
```

This works really great so far, but I don't know what to do if I have an unknown number of gallery's on my page. The html output is generated from an database. Is it possible to change the js-code so that it always work if there is a data-imagelightbox="" parameter?

I don't want to repeat the js Code at the bottom of my html page multiple times, just for changing one letter.

Thanks

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used that library, but this jquery selector should work!

Try this:

```
var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox]';
var done = array();
$( selector ).each(function(){
     var letter = $(this).attr("data-imagelightbox");
     if(done.indexOf(letter) == -1 ){
          //Prevents multiple initialisation. 
          done.push(letter);
          sel = 'a[data-imagelightbox=' + letter + ']';

          var lightbox = $( sel ).imageLightbox(
          {
              quitOnDocClick: false,
              onStart: function() { overlayOn(); closeButtonOn( lightbox ); arrowsOn( lightbox, sel ); },
              onEnd: function() { overlayOff(); closeButtonOff(); arrowsOff(); },
              onLoadStart: function() { },
              onLoadEnd: function() { $( '.imagelightbox-arrow' ).css( 'display', 'block' ); }
    });
     }
});
```

Comment: This is not working, an like Regent says, all galleries would be merged into one, that's what I don't want :)

Comment: Since I haven't used that lib before im sorry. See if my edit works. I haven't had possibilitty to test this yet so no garantues

Comment: As I understand, `arrowsOn(lightbox, selector)` should now be `arrowsOn(lightbox, sel)`. Also `$(this).attr("data-imagelightbox")` will look a little better as `$(this).data("imagelightbox")`